# Reader-Writer using semaphores and shared memory in C

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, readerwriterlock

I'm trying to make a simple reader/writer program using POSIX named semaphores, its working, but on some systems, it halts immediately on the first semaphore and thats it ... I'm really desperate by now. Can anyone help please? Its working fine on my system, so i can't track the problem by ltrace. (sorry for the comments, I'm from czech republic)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfcp44u2r0jd7fy/readerWriter.c

Comment: how did the SO allow you to create a new `tag`?

Comment: Assuming you mean readerwriterlock, that is not a new tag, even if it has no followers yet.

Comment: Try running your program through helgrind. Maybe you got your locking logic wrong.

Comment: thans, it goes through valgrind/helgrind with flying colors, I am suspecting I am using the shared memory or semaphores wrong ... now I am using sem_getvalue to debug the whole thing and it seems to be getting quite strange values

Comment: The problem is really occuring only on some systems (multicore, moderate load). Here is a ltrace log from the system where it failed http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20809963/ltrace.txt but i dont really have the skill to make something useful out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX semaphores are not well suited for application code since they are interruptible. Basically any sort of IO to your processes will mess up your signalling. Please have a look at [this post](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-make-sem_t-interrupt-safe/).

So you'd have to be really careful to interpret all error returns from the `sem_` functions properly. In the code that you posted there is no such thing.

If your implementation of POSIX supports them, just use rwlocks, they are made for this, are much higher level and don't encounter that difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've fiddled around with the semaphores for a bit and came up with this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20809963/readerWriter2.c but I'm not sure if I had eliminated any possible deadlocks ... can anyone check?

Comment: @Salamander: No, you still don't get it right. There is no point in just aborting when `sem_wait` fails, and it is completely wrong to repeat `sem_wait` without error check if doesn't fail. You'd have to check for the reasons of failure and to repeat in case of a transient error.

Comment: Do you perhaps have some example?

Comment: It seems you just saved my life ... it worked on the system which was deadlocking on the first semaphore. So thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In computer science, the readers-writers problems are examples of a common computing problem in concurrency. There are at least three variations of the problems, which deal with situations in which many threads try to access the same shared memory at one time. Some threads may read and some may write, with the constraint that no process may access the share for either reading or writing, while another process is in the act of writing to it. (In particular, it is allowed for two or more readers to access the share at the same time.) A readers-writer lock is a data structure that solves one or more of the readers-writers problems.